# any way to find out Master Node from Linux-HA cluster by "crm" command?

Tags: linux, crm, high-availability, pacemaker

I have one Linux-HA based cluster(Master Node/Slave Node), and have some resources defined on Pacemaker, my question is any way we can used by "`crm`" command to find out the Master Node of this Linux-HA cluster? I mean at the timeslot before all resource agent loaded or during resource loading?

After the resource loaded, I think we can use `crm_mon` or "`crm status`" and grep resource on Master Node to identify it. but I cannot finger out a way to find out before or during resource loading.

thanks, 
Emre

Answer (score 4):

Before loading resources completed, there is no active node. DC does not mean that is active node

Comment: Does not mean that is active node. Sorry for my typo

Answer (score 0):

crm status will give you the current DC (Designated Co-ordinator).  This is the "Master Node".